# How to make imports works in a console script when installing by setuptools in Python?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Usually I create consoles scripts in Python, but does not uses the setup tools.
Now I am trying to use the setuptools to automatically manages local installation and make it ready for distribution.

I stumble in a problem that may be a little ordinary, but could not find anything in Google.

Usually in run a console script with `python3 my_script.py`, and there are `imports` statement that is normally loaded.

But when installing by setuptools, I got the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'My_Object'

... if I try to locally import a module called `My_Object`.

Shouldn't setuptools also installs the module dependencies to make the script works? Or something is missing in the setup file?

Here are my `setup.py` file content in the project root:

```
from setuptools import setup

VERSION = '0.0.1'

def readme():
    with open('README.md') as f:
        return f.read()

setup(
    name='object-test',
    version=VERSION,
    description="Test setup script",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    long_description=readme(),
    keywords="Testing import in installation",
    author="Danilo Silva",
    author_email="contact@danilocgsilva.me",
    packages=["src"],
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["importtest=src.entry:main"],},
    include_package_data=True
)
```

Following, the content from the `entry.py` file inside my local `src` folder:

```
from My_Object import My_Object

def main():
    print("Hello! This is just an application test for importing")
    my_object = My_Object()
    print(my_object.main())

# main()
```

And `My_Object.py` file, also inside `src` folder:

```
class My_Object:

    def main(self):
        return 'Hello! And this is the imported output!'
```

Usually, I uncomment the last `main()` in `entry.py` just to check that everything is working fine, then run the script typing in console `python3 entry.py`. This ensures that everything is ok in my script and no `ModuleNotFoundError` is thrown.

How to make the import statements works in a console script installed by setuptools? What am I missing?

Comment: What command do you call once the project is installed? You should call `importtest`, is that what you do? What does `My_Module` refer to? I don't see any `My_Module` in the code you added to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I just corrected my post. When I got the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'My_Module'` I was trying to mean 'My_Object'. And yes, after installing I call `importtest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, I believe the first line of the `src/entry.py` file should read:

```
from src.My_Object import My_Object
```

Since as it is setup, `src` is the *top-level* package containing the `My_Object` module.